# Numpy for specific color section extraction

Tags: python, numpy, colors, grayscale

I'm pretty new to python and trying to separate colored sections in an image from the grayscaled.
Although this code (see below) gets me the results I'm looking for, it takes way to long (10+ seconds on normal images).

I looked for one hour and didn't find an appropriate answer, as most just separate specific colors (black, white, ...) or thresholds.

As far as I (already) know numpy is the way to go, but I was not successful :S

Looking forward for help - Thanks!!

```
    gray_elements = np.zeros_like(image)
    gray_elements[:] = 255

    colored_segments = np.zeros_like(image)
    colored_segments[:] = 255
    
    # Separate black-to-white-colors from colored
    for y in range(image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(image.shape[1]):

            pxl = image[y, x]
            if max(pxl) - min(pxl) > 5:
                colored_segments[y, x] = pxl
            else:
                gray_elements[y, x] = pxl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but as it's St Patrick's Day...

If you have a Numpy array `na` containing a 3-channel RGB image, it will have `na.shape` of `(h,w,3)`.

You can get the maximum of the 3 channels at each point with:

```
ma = np.amax(na, axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

and the minimum with:

```
mi = np.amin(na, axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

then the difference with:

```
diff = ma - mi
```

Then make a Boolean (true/false) mask with:

```
grey = diff < 5
```

If/when you become more familiar with Numpy, you'd probably use the  [peak-to-peak](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) function.

---

Normally though, you would use **OpenCV**, to convert to [HSL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colourspace and then find pixels where the Saturation channel is low, meaning the colour is unsaturated and rather grey.

Comment: Thanks very much! Saved my day! Ended up with a bit more code, but it's way faster now ;)
+1